# How to extract nested parentheses in sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to extract whitespace separated columns with `sed`. Here is an example with `ps`:

```
$ ps | sed -n -E "s/^(\s*([^\s]+)){4}.*$/\0/p"
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 8446 pts/185  00:00:00 ps
 8447 pts/185  00:00:00 sed
54326 pts/185  00:00:00 bash
$ ps | sed -n -E "s/^(\s*([^\s]+)){4}.*$/\1/p"
D
t
t
t
```

Why it does this way? How to specify nested parentheses?

---

I would like to get column of PIDs (in this example).

---

I found that I can't process non-nested parentheses either:

```
$ ps > out.txt
$ cat out.txt
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
14819 pts/185  00:00:00 ps
54326 pts/185  00:00:00 bash
$ cat out.txt | sed -n -E "s/^\s*([^\s]+)\s*([^\s]+)\s*([^\s]+)\s*([^\s]+).*$/\2/p"
C


$
```

In last case it prints line with `C` and 2 emptyy lines.

Why???

Comment: I don't think you can use a capture group of `\0` . AND use `[[:space:]]` instead of `\s` ? Also edit your Q to show your required output from that input. Good luck.

Comment: @Cyrus what's wrong with what is posted?

Comment: Agree with Cyrus . Your `ps` output is being post processed by `sed`. Don't make us guess if some of the `sed` is working, please. AND please show required output. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I ensure you, that the output of `ps` alone is the same as in my first printout (except of addition of `sed` process itself). You can try it on your own computer if you don't believe me.

Comment: You want the first column? Are you familiar with `cut`? Or if you prefer sed, how about `sed 's/\([^ ]\) .*/\1/'`?

Comment: @Beta I prefer `sed`. I want to be able to extract any column number, first is just an example. If I provide an example, I am answered with specific recipes for that example. If I don't provide an example, I am asked to provide it. Is it possible to ask for general hints here?

Comment: The trouble was that your description was vague and ambiguous. But I think I've got it now.

Comment: With awk: `awk '{print $1}' out.txt`

Comment: If you just want the pids, why not just do `ps -o pid`?

Comment: And if you want an arbitrary column from whitespace separated columns, use awk: `awk '{print $n}' n=$column`

Comment: @Cyrus what if regex is more complex? what if I want to split by `@` and by `:`, then what? Is `sed` unusable?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I don't want pids, I want to understand `sed`.

Comment: If you want to split by `@` and `:`, use  `awk '{print $2}' FS='[@:]'`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the raw file is

```
a1  a2 a3 a4
b1 b2 b3 b4
c1  c2 c3 c4
d1 d2 d3 d4
```

(If there is leading whitespace, remove it in a separate operation, `'s/^ *//'`)

Without extended regular expressions, you can do this:

```
sed 's/\([^ ][^ ]* *\)\{3\}.*/\1/'
```

which will yield

```
a3
b3
c3
d3
```

Extended regular expressions *might* make this a little cleaner, but not all implementations support backreferences, so the logic would be a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

First, please avoid double quotes unless you want the shell to interpret it (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

`awk` is better suited for field processing, but I'll try to provide a `sed` solution with explanations (assuming `GNU sed` as `\s` is used)

```
$ sed -n -E 's/^(\s*([^\s]+)){4}.*$/\1/p' ip.txt
D
t
t
t
```

- `^` start of line anchor
- `[^\s]` this won't work as you wanted, it will match other than `\` and `s` characters. `\s`, `\S`, `\w` and `\W` are not recognized by `sed` inside character classes, in this case you can simply use `\S` though
- `(\s*([^\s]+))` you probably intended to capture only the field value by using two capture groups
- `{4}` however, when quantifier is used, only the last match will be available for backreferencing, other matches is overridden. (further reading: https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html)
- because of `\s*` string like `CMD` matched as multiple fields in above case
- also, not sure why you are using `-n` and `p` instead of leaving them out

To get specific column, I'd use:

```
$ sed -E 's/^\s*(\S+).*/\1/' ip.txt
PID
8446
8447
54326

$ sed -E 's/^\s*\S+\s+(\S+).*/\1/' ip.txt
TTY
pts/185
pts/185
pts/185

$ sed -E 's/^\s*\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+).*/\1/' ip.txt
TIME
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
```

Which gives us the following generic formula:

```
$ sed -E 's/^\s*(\S+\s+){0}(\S+).*/\2/' ip.txt
PID
8446
8447
54326
$ sed -E 's/^\s*(\S+\s+){1}(\S+).*/\2/' ip.txt
TTY
pts/185
pts/185
pts/185
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 's/\S+/\n&\n/1;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*/\1/p' file
```

This surrounds the nth column (in this example column 1) by newlines then uses pattern matching to remove the fields and newlines either side.

Alternatively:

```
sed -nE 's/^(\s*(\S+)){4}.*/\2/p' file
```

This will return the 4th field.